# Why does the resolution of my Logitech C920 webcam with open cv go down a lot with Windows compared with Mac OS?

Tags: opencv, camera, webcam, logitech

When I use my Logitech C920 on my Mac, I get high quality 1080p resolution.  But when I plug it into my Windows laptop, the default is 640x480.  I increased the resolution setting to 1080, but it appears as though it's just upsampling from the default low res, and not actually high quality.  How can I increase the quality?

I also tried using the default Logitech software, and that does increase the quality, so it seems possible on my Windows, however, I need the high quality with OpenCV, not the default software.  Thanks!

```
class MyCam:

    def __init__(self):
        self.vs = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
        time.sleep(1.5)
        self.vs.set(3,1920)
        self.vs.set(4,1080)
```

Comment: i forgot the name of the backend used in VideoCapture in Windows, but it gives a lot more possibilities to parametrize the device. Have a look at direct draw filtergraphs too, maybe there are different pins to use.

Comment: Which version of OpenCV do you use?